# Angular refresh browser back to initial page

Tags: angular

I have a SPA Angular 9, when I refresh (F5) from the browser, the app is reinitialized and returns to the home page. I use `PathLocationStrategy`. The server is configured that on 404 errors goes from the index.html. How can I solve the problem?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent },
  { path: 'resetpassword', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'logoutok', component: LogoutokComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**SOLVED:**

I solved the problem on the server I was doing a redirect to index.html and not a forwarding.

Comment: Can you provide us with your RouterModule configuration?

Comment: If possible serve angular `index.html` file on 404 error, and handle 404 page by angular. (Set a defined route for home and use `redirectTo` for unknown path)